# RandomAccessFile.write: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)

Tags: java

I'm getting `java.io.IOException: write failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)` when trying to write a `RandomAccessFile`.

```
    RandomAccessFile raf;
    try {
        raf = new RandomAccessFile("foo", "r");
        byte bytes[] = "test".getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
        raf.write(bytes);
        raf.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
    } catch (IOException e){
    }
```

Why do I get this exception?

Answer (score 2):

Use "rw" instead of "r" when creating the `RandomAccessFile`.

Comment: I think you’re right, but your answer would be more valuable if you describe why, and what “r” and “rw” mean